# Is it possible to reorder a table in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot, tidyr, reshape

I have a table as belowe:

```
dput(df)
structure(list(Samples = c("Cont-4", "Cont-4", "Cont-4", "Cont-4", 
"Cont-4", "Cont-4", "Cont-4", "Cont-4", "Cont-4", "Cont-4", "Cont-4", 
"Cont-4", "Cont-4", "Cont-4", "Cont-4", "Cont-2", "Cont-2", "Cont-2", 
"Cont-2", "Cont-2", "Cont-2", "Cont-2", "Cont-2", "Cont-2", "Cont-2", 
"Cont-2", "Cont-2", "Cont-2", "Cont-2", "Cont-2"), Gene_Name = c("Actin", 
"Actin", "Actin", "DnaJ", "DnaJ", "DnaJ", "EF", "EF", "EF", "EZ-1", 
"EZ-1", "EZ-1", "TF-1", "TF-1", "TF-1", "Actin", "Actin", "Actin", 
"DnaJ", "DnaJ", "DnaJ", "EF", "EF", "EF", "EZ-1", "EZ-1", "EZ-1", 
"TF-1", "TF-1", "TF-1"), Cq = c(18.99, 18.45, 18.67, 23.87, 24.29, 
24.1, 20.46, 20.34, 20.52, 21.05, 20.79, 21.01, 25.71, 25.57, 
25.72, 20.46, 20.16, 20.2, 25.86, 25.8, 25.84, 22.25, 23.07, 
21.95, 22.25, 22.14, 22.15, 25.64, 25.9, 25.45)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -30L))
```

I want wider table in which, each gene locate at separate column.
what I want is below for example:

```
dput(df2)
structure(list(Samples = c("Cont-4", "Cont-4", "Cont-4", "Cont-2", 
"Cont-2", "Cont-2"), ACT = c(18.99, 18.45, 18.67, 20.46, 20.16, 
20.2), DnaJ = c(23.87, 24.29, 24.1, 25.86, 25.8, 25.84), EF = c(20.46, 
20.34, 20.52, 22.25, 23.07, 21.95), `EZ-1` = c(21.05, 20.79, 
21.01, 22.25, 22.14, 22.15), `TF-1` = c(25.71, 25.57, 25.72, 
25.64, 25.9, 25.45)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Answer (score 3):

This is not as trivial as it might seem:

Here's the trick: We have to account for duplicates by adding a unique identifier with `id` AFTER grouping. Try to group before `id` -> it won't work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Gene_Name) %>%
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gene_Name, values_from = Cq) %>% 
  select(-id)
```

```
# A tibble: 6 × 6
  Samples Actin  DnaJ    EF `EZ-1` `TF-1`
  <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1 Cont-4   19.0  23.9  20.5   21.0   25.7
2 Cont-4   18.4  24.3  20.3   20.8   25.6
3 Cont-4   18.7  24.1  20.5   21.0   25.7
4 Cont-2   20.5  25.9  22.2   22.2   25.6
5 Cont-2   20.2  25.8  23.1   22.1   25.9
6 Cont-2   20.2  25.8  22.0   22.2   25.4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `pivot_wider` + `unnest` from `{tidyr}`.

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gene_Name, values_from = Cq, values_fn = list) %>%
  unnest(-1)

# # A tibble: 6 × 6
#   Samples Actin  DnaJ    EF `EZ-1` `TF-1`
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 Cont-4   19.0  23.9  20.5   21.0   25.7
# 2 Cont-4   18.4  24.3  20.3   20.8   25.6
# 3 Cont-4   18.7  24.1  20.5   21.0   25.7
# 4 Cont-2   20.5  25.9  22.2   22.2   25.6
# 5 Cont-2   20.2  25.8  23.1   22.1   25.9
# 6 Cont-2   20.2  25.8  22.0   22.2   25.4
```

---

If the length of each group is unequal, we need to expand each vector to the maximal size.

```r
df %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Gene_Name, values_from = Cq,
              values_fn = \(x) list(x[seq_len(max(tapply(., ~ Samples + Gene_Name, nrow)))])) %>%
  unnest(-1)
```

Comment: This was my first solution. But somehow I can't get values_fn = list in my brain. I see it works, but can't imagine why! Therefore I went back to id and group_by.

Answer (score 3):

A base R option with `ave` + `reshape`

```
reshape(
    transform(
        df,
        id = ave(seq_along(Samples), Samples, Gene_Name, FUN = seq_along)
    ),
    direction = "wide",
    idvar = c("id", "Samples"),
    timevar = "Gene_Name"
)[-2]
```

which gives

```
   Samples Cq.Actin Cq.DnaJ Cq.EF Cq.EZ-1 Cq.TF-1
1   Cont-4    18.99   23.87 20.46   21.05   25.71
2   Cont-4    18.45   24.29 20.34   20.79   25.57
3   Cont-4    18.67   24.10 20.52   21.01   25.72
16  Cont-2    20.46   25.86 22.25   22.25   25.64
17  Cont-2    20.16   25.80 23.07   22.14   25.90
18  Cont-2    20.20   25.84 21.95   22.15   25.45
```